# how would you build pinterest like page with meteor.js

Tags: meteor, pinterest

I hope all of you know the pinterest style layout and its behaviour:

- we have collection of many (let's say 1000) products
- on page load we display only little subset of that collection (i.e. 20 first products)
- when user scrolls down and reach bottom of the page, we render next 20 products
- page is viewed by many clients, and each has its own set of displayed products

Bonus task:

- when Products collection gets new items, they are displayed on top of the page (as first items in displayed products list)

I am thinking **how to program that logic in Meteor way**. Let's skip user interface code, I am interested only in business logic.

I am thinking about ProductsDisplayed collection as helper, which is empty and populated by 20 products on page load, then when scrolling point is reached, I insert 20 products more from original Products collection etc.

Problems:

- how to have different ProductsDisplayed collections between clients,
- how to ask for next 20 products from Products collection, and don't get the previous ones

But maybe the whole idea about ProductsDisplayed is wrong. I would love to know what do you think!

**Update!**
I changed approach to using only Products collection.

server:

```
Meteor.publish "productsDisplayed", (number) ->
  Products.find {},
    limit: number
```

client:

```
Meteor.autosubscribe ->
  Meteor.subscribe "productsDisplayed", Session.get('productsDisplayedNumber')
```

and incrementing by 20 Session 'productsDisplayedNumber' when scrolling point reached. But autosubscribe makes that the whole template is rerendered, not only the new elements.
Any ideas?

Comment: Nice app! It's good to see an actual Meteor app!

Answer (score 5):

I finally solved this problem. The solution is to have client only Collection, like that:

```
# on client
# client side only collection
ProductsDisplayed = new Meteor.Collection(null)
```

then when scrolling point is reached ask server for next N (`limitNo`) products

```
# on client
Meteor.call 'getProducts', limitNo, skipNo, (err, products) =>

  _.each products, (item, index) =>
    # get rid of _id
    delete item._id

    ProductsDisplayed.insert( item )
```

`skipNo` is incremented by N, to always ask for next set of data. And on server side I have:

```
# on server
Meteor.methods
  getProducts: (limitNo, skipNo) ->

    productsCursor = Products.find( {}, {
      limit: limitNo,
      skip: skipNo
    })

    productsCursor.fetch()
```

this Meteor method returns me next set of products from Products collection.

Of course view template displays ProductsDisplayed collection content:

```
Template.products.products = ->
  ProductsDisplayed.find {}
```

So, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks for updating your own question!