# Publishing structured, reactive data to the client (outside of database collections)

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor

I am looking for the most performant solution for sending structured data to the client in the Meteor framework on a request.

**THE ISSUE:**
Sometimes, before you send data from the database to the client, you want to add some server side generated additional information beeing sent to the client (i.e. security credentials for many objects). This data can be time-critical (i.e. due to an expiration timestamp) and therefore should not be stored in the db. Also, this data sometimes cannot be processed on the client side (i.e. due to security reasons). In many cases, this data will be structurally related to actual database data, but also very much related to a single request, since you might want to have it discarded and re-generated on a new request.

**YOU CAN (at least by design..):**

1. create a second collection, store and publish your request-related data there, accepting the write-overhead, and then i.e. in the `Meteor.myTemplate.destroyed=function(){...}` remove the data again accepting another write-overhead.
2. store each entry in a session variable, but then you also have to take care
   of deleting it later on (`Meteor.myTemplate.destroyed=function(){...}`), this is my favourite right now, but I am running into problems with storing large objects there.
3. store this data in the dom (i.e. in the attributes or data fields of hidden or visible elements)
4. generate this data from the dom with `Meteor.call('method',arguments,callback(){...})` by storing the appropriate `arguments` in the dom and injecting them back with i.e. jQuery in the `callback(){...}`.

**YOU CAN'T: (by design!!)**

1. use transformations within `Meteor.publish("name",function(){...})` on the server
2. use a `Meteor.call()` within a transformation on a `Template.variable=function(){return collection.find(...)}` (also not if you have a corresponding `Meteor.method()` on the client for guessing the result!).

Again, what I am looking for is the best performing solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim Mack created a nice example here that proves, how well it works to store db data as well as additional "transform" properties in a Session variable.
Unfortunately this example lacks reactivity and does not perform the desired "transformations" after Meteor's magic re-render. So I grabbed his cool code and added back the reactivity, it's slim code that works very well, but will be outperformed by Jim Mack's example in terms of efficiency.

**lolz.html**

```
<head>
  <title>lolz</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>myItems}}
</body>

<template name="myItems">
    <h3>Reactive Item List with additional properties</h3>
    <button id="add">add</button>
    <button id="remove">remove</button>
    <dl>
        {{#each items}}
            <dt>data: {{caption}}</dt>
            <dd>added property: {{anotherProp _id}}</dd>
        {{/each}}
    </dl>
</template>
```

**lolz.js**

```
items = new Meteor.Collection('Items');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    items.allow({
    insert: function (userid, doc) {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function(userid,doc){
        return true;
    }
  });
  while(items.find().count()>0){
    items.remove(items.findOne()._id);
  }
  while (items.find().count() < 3) {
        items.insert({caption: 'LOLCATZ RULZ'});
    }
  Meteor.publish('Items', function () {
      return items.find();
  });
  Meteor.methods({
        'getAdditionalProps': function() {
            additionalProps={};
        items.find().forEach(function(doc){
            additionalProps[doc._id]=reverse(doc.caption);
      });
      return additionalProps;
    }
  });

    function reverse(s){ // server side operation, i.e. for security reasons
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
    };
}

if (Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe('Items');

    Meteor.startup(function(){
        getAdditionalProps();
        itemsHandle=items.find().observe({
            added : function(doc){
                getAdditionalProps();
            },
            removed : function(doc){
                getAdditionalProps();
            },
            changed : function(docA,docB){
                getAdditionalProps();
            }
        });
    });

    Template.myItems.rendered=function(){
        console.log(new Date().getTime());
    };

    Template.myItems.items=function(){
        return items.find();
    }

    Template.myItems.anotherProp=function(id){
        return Session.get('additionalProps')[id];
    }

    Template.myItems.events({
        'click #add':function(e,t){
            items.insert({caption: 'LOLCATZ REACTZ'});
        },
        'click #remove':function(e,t){
            items.remove(items.findOne()._id);
        }
    });
}

function getAdditionalProps(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        Meteor.call('getAdditionalProps',function(error,props){
            Session.set('additionalProps',props);
        });
    },0);
}
```

Comment: so, I would make additional props a separate collection, and store nothing in the session in this case.  I know you have voiced reasons why not to do this.  I think my strongest argument is that it's taking advantage of a central feature of Meteor, which they optimize as much as they can.

Comment: Very true, just in this case I think I really won't miss the features of the Meteor Collection, it's more like a workaround for syncing some missing features to the Collection itself. And it is very inefficiently causing re-renders. I am still trying to fix this but I am stuck at another issue with Meteor's observer tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645334

Comment: Hey, if you are having slow refreshes, do you have a div around the elements for each document, with an id?  Like <div id="cats_{{_id}}">

Comment: Refreshes are speedy, but happen too often. When the list gets longer, I get a dozen of re-renders with each item added to the collection. I've put it on the hub: https://github.com/iamnotachoice/meteor-transform-on-publish-workaround

Comment: I am more interested in the code you are having problems with, than in the code you wrote to cope with them.  I continue to think your re-render problem not to be a design flaw in Meteor.  Have you seen http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance#.UilnIlFDulg

Comment: Yepp, read that already. You mean the meteor core code? The re-render problem is definitely my own fault since the feedback line in the `Meteor.call()` changes the db-data during the render causing it to re-render again and again until the db-change stops. I kind of need to make my Meteor.call() blocking, so that it does not return until it has retrieved the data. Or somehow pausing the reactivity until then. Maybe using a collection instead of a session variable solves the issue, I am currently testing this.

Answer (score 2):

To address the transform issue, which I care about because I think in terms of smart models doing things rather than a bunch of anonymous functions, here is an example of server transform reaching the client (not reactive as is, through a call, not a publish, but illustrative of the point under discussion of server transforms).

You will get this:

```
each image local

data: LOLCATZ RULZ
  transform:
data: LOLCATZ RULZ
  transform:

each image server transformed

data: LOLCATZ RULZ
  transform: XYZ
data: LOLCATZ RULZ
  transform: XYZ
```

from:

```
<template name='moritz'>
    <h3>each image local</h3>
    <dl>
        {{#each images}}
        <dt>data: {{caption}}</dt>
        <dd>transform: {{secretPassword}}</dd>
        {{/each}}
    </dl>

    <h3>each image server transformed</h3>
    <dl>
        {{#each transformed}}
        <dt>data: {{caption}}</dt>
        <dd>transform: {{secretPassword}}</dd>
        {{/each}}
    </dl>
</template>

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Images = new Meteor.Collection('images', {
        transform: function (doc) {
            doc.secretPassword = 'XYZ'
            return doc
        }
    });

    Images.allow({
        insert: function (userid, doc) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (Images.find().count() < 1) {
        Images.insert({ caption: 'LOLCATZ RULZ'});
    }

    Meteor.publish('images', function () {
        return Images.find();
    })

    Meteor.methods({
        'transformed': function() {
            return Images.find().fetch();
        }
    })
}
else {
    Images = new Meteor.Collection('images');

    imageSub = Meteor.subscribe('images');

    Template.moritz.helpers({
        'images': function () {
            console.log(Images.find().count() + ' images')
            return Images.find();
        },
        'transformed': function () {
            // Should be separated, call should be in route for example
            Meteor.call('transformed', function(err,data){
               Session.set('transformed', data);     
                });
            return Session.get('transformed');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just tested it and I can confirm it works like a charm. I did not even try something like that! Thank you for sharing this cool solution!!

Comment: :)  I'm using transform to a class including methods, and dropping most of my helpers.  But then you have to transform on the client.

Comment: Oh man you defenitely saved me here, now this is very elegant. I even can skip the ´transform´ when creating the collection, I just put it directly in the `find({},{...})` within the `Meteor.call(...)` for beeing flexible on how I transform this. Awesome!! Thank you!!

Comment: Hey Jim, check out my example below, I took your code and added back the reactivity. I will give you the well earned upvote as soon as I have 15 reputation, I'm still a subhuman here with my 12 reps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Meteor Streams](http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/), you can send something directly to the client from the server without having to use collections on the client.

You could do something with the message you get (I'm using an example from the meteor-streams site):

Client

```
chatStream.on('message', function(message) {
    if(message.expiry > new Date()) {
        //Do something with the message (not being read from a collection)
    }
});
```

Even though you do this with some intent on not having it stored, be wary that simple tools (Chrome Inspector) can peak into the Network/Websocket tab (even if its encrypted via SSL) and see the raw data being passed through.

While i'm not sure of your intentions, if this is for security in any scenario never trust whatever data you get from the client.

Comment: Yeah Meteor Streams looks really good, it looks like it can be used for lots of purposes. Thank you very much for that hint! I am not bothering about Chrome Inspector, my intention is generating policies on the server, signing them on the server with a secret key and sending them to the client. They will than be related to links to files in my s3 bucket which I have stored in a regular monogdb collection. The policies will however expire, and thats why should be created 'on-demand' and not be stored since they are only retrieved once and would be just overhead data in the db.

Comment: Ok I got it, so Session var or Collection makes no big difference for this. The render issue is resolved by using the observer callback instead of the rendered callback. Works speedy now! Still it's a workaround for the actual publish function not sending transformations to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line would seem ideally answered by 'Mongo collections' but then I read a few conflicting ideas and conclusions I'm not sure I agree with.  (For example, why can't you do those two things?  Because it must happen on the server?) The most confusing statement for me is:

This data can be time-critical (i.e. due to an expiration timestamp) and therefore should not be stored in the db.

I don't understand what assumptions go into that conclusion, but if you consider storing data in the dom to be plausible, per points 2 and three above, you would seem to be open to systems much less performant than a mongo db.

You know you can, from the server, publish a second collection of the additional server-generated calculations, which you generate on the fly from the data, and put that together with the data once on the client.  Kind of like a parent-child relationship: as you display the client document, pull up the additional data from the server from the dynamic collection and work it into your templates.

Comment: First: All things in the "You can't"-list are just not possibly by design in (vanilla) Meteor as far as I know. Of course you could create a second collection, I will add that to the "you-can"-list. However, I am really looking for a solution without storing data in a db for security and overhead reasons. More something like `Meteor.call()`, just returning the server-generated value when called within `Template.myTemplate.variable=function(){...}` or `Meteor.myTemplate.created=function(){...}` Thank you for the input!

Comment: Ok, to Can't #1: I have used transformations on server.  You just can't use eJson to stream transformed objects to client if they include functions.  I also use transforms in the scenario "can't 2", if I understand what you've written, so possibly there is a syntax clarification possible.

Comment: Also, beware premature optimization. Your time programming is also part of the equation, and staying standard until you have measurements of the system as a whole is a tried and true approach.  It may be more fun to roll your own, but could you prove a need at this stage?

Comment: Hey Jim, no doubt transformations work on the sever, but in can't #1 I state they do not work on in the `Meteor.publish("name",function(){...})` on the return object. This is by design and makes sense since the published collection is sync with the client collections and the Meteor sync idea makes no sense with transformations on the server.

Comment: proving a need.. so if you use filepicker or s3 over http you will probably store InkBlobs/s3-Links in your db, publishing them to the client when needed. If you use the security model then, you also have to send security credentials. In my eyes, these credentials are structured data, related to both db and request, that needs to be published but not stored in the db. Does that make sense in any way? I am not asking for a non-standard solution here, just the best implementation within the standard. Right now I send the data with `Meteor.call()` and store it in the minimongo.

Comment: Moritz, Thanks for helping me see I had been miss-interpreting some transform experiences I had previously.  Am confused!

Comment: For real? For me it just doesn't transform at all, just puts out the original collection. I came to the conclusion that this must by by design due to the fairydust-syncing in meteor.. I am still looking for the most reasonable alternative to those transformations.