# Meteor.call not firing on the server, fine in the console

Tags: meteor

I have a server method:

server/methods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
removeStructure: function(id) {
    this.unblock();
    console.log("method removestructure was called on "+ id);
    Structure.remove({"overlay_id": id}, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Deleted " + result + " structures.");
        }
    });
}
```

It is invoked in an observer when a document is removed from a collection:

client/x.js

```
Overlays.find().observe({    
    removed: function(item) {
        console.log('Overlay removed' );
        if ( Meteor.isClient ) {
            drawnItems.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                if (layer.meteor_id == item._id) {
                    drawnItems.removeLayer(layer);
                }
            });
        }
        console.log("attempting to remove meteor id " + item._id);
        Meteor.call("removeStructure", item._id);
    }
});
```

Nothing happens. The trace "attempting to remove meteor id jykkcEJuBL4NfJdte" fires, but the meteor method does not get called on the server. No error is returned client or server, it's as if it skips clean over that line.

When I type into the client browser console

`Meteor.call("removeStructure", "jykkcEJuBL4NfJdte");`

It runs no problem on the server and client.

What could be going wrong here? Am stumped!

Comment: Is that `removed` a helper method you created or is it in an observeChanges?

Comment: It's in an Observe changes `Overlays.find().observe({  ...code }); ` - have updated the question with this detail

Comment: I'm wondering if you hit this "Finally, if you are inside a stub on the client and call another method, the other method is not executed (no RPC is generated, nothing "real" happens)." I wonder if Meteor considers `removed` a client side stub so it's not using your call. Can you try moving `x.js` out of the client directory so the observe changes will be both client and server side?

Comment: This solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645334/meteor-meteor-call-from-within-observe-callback-does-not-execute